# How get product id that contains in two terms category type and group type

Tags: mysql, sql

How get product id that contains in two terms category type and group type

I have one table ec_terms
[image]

and ec_terms_product

[image]

How I can get product IDs that contains both alias best-offers and  premium-cars
?

in this case, the product ID should be 4.

Tried this but did not get anything out

```
SELECT *, count(ec_terms_product.product_id) AS coutp 
FROM ec_terms_product 
LEFT JOIN ec_terms 
ON ec_terms_product.term_id = ec_terms.id 
WHERE 1=1 
AND (ec_terms.alias IN ('best-offers') AND ec_terms.alias IN ('premium-cars'))
GROUP BY ec_terms_product.term_id ,ec_terms_product.product_id
```

can you help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT etp.product_id
FROM ec_terms_product etp JOIN
     ec_terms et 
     ON etp.term_id = et.id 
GROUP BY etp.product_id 
HAVING SUM(et.alias = 'best-offers') > 0 AND
       SUM(at.alias = 'premium-cars') > 0;
```

Note that a `LEFT JOIN` is not necessary.  A `LEFT JOIN` just adds overhead to the query.

An even more efficient method is:

```
SELECT etp.product_id
FROM ec_terms_product etp JOIN
     ec_terms et 
     ON etp.term_id = et.id 
WHERE et.alias IN ('best-offers', 'premium-cars')
GROUP BY etp.product_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

- **Group by** on `product_id`.
- Using [Group_concat with Distinct](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), get all various aliases of the product in a comma separated string.
- Using [Find_in_set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function in Having clause, you can filter out the product id(s)
- You dont need to do `Left Join` since you want to consider only those product_id(s) which have alias values. So, simply use `Inner join`.

Try the following:

```
SELECT etp.product_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT et.alias) AS aliases 
FROM ec_terms_product AS etp 
INNER JOIN ec_terms AS et 
ON etp.term_id = et.id 
GROUP BY etp.product_id 
HAVING FIND_IN_SET('best-offers', aliases) > 0 
   AND FIND_IN_SET('premium-cars', aliases) > 0
```

Comment: @ВикторЛернер . . . Although this answer is correct, it unnecessarily combines everything into a string and then searches through the string.  These not only add overhead, but `GROUP_CONCAT()` is (by defalt) limited in size.  There are simpler ways of implementing the same logic.

Comment: agreed with sir gordon